# Citrix IE detection

Tags: internet-explorer, citrix

We have a website, which many users are accessing through Citrix. Certain things (namely video) drag down the Citrix server so much that I don't even want to try launching a video if the user is connecting from that.

Is there some way (on the web server end) of detecting if the browser that's connecting is being hosted by citrix? Everyone will be using IE 7 or 8 if that is relevant. I did a dump of all the request parameters and scanned through window.* and window.navigator.* but didn't seem to find anything.

Comment: You're more likely to get a response over at http://serverfault.com/, since this site is about programming related issues/questions.

Comment: @Gert: yeah, this is kind of halfway between. I don't care to learn how to administrate a citrix server, but I suppose the kind of people who would know the answer to my question are citrix admins.

Answer (score 1):

Just saw a potentially relevant answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817172/web-browser-control-under-citrix-environment) which led to more info [here](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX106094).

It is possible to configure Citrix in a way to launch specific content (such as video) on the local client instead of Citrix, if certain conditions are met.

This may or may not be useful in your specific situation, but it might be worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this via the browser, but connecting from CITRIX should be from a known IP pool on the CITRIX-side, can you check the IP the user is connecting (to the web server) with against that list/pool/range?

Whatever's configured for CITRIX to hand out to it's users, use that list/pool/range for comparison...this will be a more assured/simpler way to do detection.  I'm assuming here that you have access to this information, since it sounds like you're hosting both CITRIX and the web server.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not hosting the citrix servers. And there are a large number of such servers. So keeping a list of all the IP ranges would be difficult, if not impossible.

Comment: @Xodarap - I'm not sure you have any options here then...unless you change the IE installs on the CITRIX servers in some way that you can detect, e.g. messing with the UserAgent, some other install, etc...there's no base way to detect this, at least that I've ever seen.

Comment: Yes, changing the UserAgent might be something to look into: http://www.pctools.com/guides/registry/detail/799