# Web browser Control under Citrix environment

Tags: ms-office, webbrowser-control, citrix, winforms-to-web

I have a web application which is also displayed in a web browser control of a winforms application. MS Word and Excel are installed on Citrix server.

But I want to open a word/excel document on client's machine instead of Citrix server when I click a link on the website (which is displaying in web browser control)

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Citrix supports a mechanism called Content Redirection which can redirect specified filetypes either to server or to client.

See this [Server-to-client Content Redirection Explained](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX113457#prodrelated) for an explanation.

Comment: Thanks, that's a real useful link.

Answer (score 0):

In order to communicate with the client computer, you will need to have software running on the client computer to accept and interpret commands from the hosted application.

We had something similar here. Clients needed a way to print to a special printer (for whatever reason the printer was not compatible with citrix). We had to create a "listening" app for the client computer and modified the hosted app to send commands via winsock\tcpip. So when a print job was requested, the hosted app sent command data to the listening app on the client and the client actually started the print job.